# sql - how can i tell which table has output

Tags: sql, union

```
SELECT sender, date FROM msg
UNION ALL
SELECT sender, date FROM chat ORDER BY date DESC
```

How can i tell which table (msg or chat) showed each of outputs

eg of output : sender |  date  |  table used

solution (weak) : add a row named "type" to each tables to differ between them

Comment: Why would your solution be weak?

Comment: thanks, i thought there would be a better idea

Comment: @Billysenders . . . There isn't.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, it's done